# Intersection Observer callback function is not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is a minor one, first of all am a beginner
so, am trying to simulate a lazy loading effect on images
My code works as expected however if I scroll down to the end of the page
then I refresh the page (not on fiddle but on vs code five server) the callback function doesn't work as expected
here is my code

```js
const allImg = document.querySelectorAll('.feature-img');
const lazyLoad = function (entries, observer) {
  const [entry] = entries;
  if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
  // let's pretend that we replaced a low res img with a high res one
  entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
  entry.target.addEventListener('load', function () {
    entry.target.classList.remove('lazy-img');
  });
};
const imgObs = new IntersectionObserver(lazyLoad, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
});
allImg.forEach(img => imgObs.observe(img));
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .welcome {
        background-color: #495057;
        height: 100vh;
        color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 44px;
      }
      .features {
        margin-top: 88px;
        padding: 0 62px;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .features-title {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .features-text {
        font-size: 22px;
      }
      .feature-img {
        width: 70%;
      }
      .text {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      .features-imgs {
        margin-top: 88px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
        row-gap: 12px;
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .lazy-img {
        filter: blur(10px);
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>lazy loading</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="welcome">
      <h1>Implementing lazy loading with Intersection Observer API</h1>
    </div>
    <section class="features">
      <div class="features-title">
        <h1 class="features-header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
        <p class="features-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti
          officiis ratione, itaque amet impedit illo porro quasi blanditiis.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="features-imgs">
        <img
          src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/f26de7fefb321605eb11cd67397c358b.jpeg"
          alt="tech"
          class="feature-img lazy-img"
          data-src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/f26de7fefb321605eb11cd67397c358b.jpeg"
        />
        <div class="tech-1-text text">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga
            dignissimos dolorem eligendi ab quibusdam perferendis at deleniti
            magnam aperiam iste.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/641ab6e364a2b173c726859696520c68.jpeg"
          alt="tech"
          class="feature-img lazy-img"
          data-src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/641ab6e364a2b173c726859696520c68.jpeg"
        />
        <div class="tech-2-text text">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga
            dignissimos dolorem eligendi ab quibusdam perferendis at deleniti
            magnam aperiam iste.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/822a79ee4043acce3e395eae316811d5.jpeg"
          alt="tech"
          class="feature-img lazy-img"
          data-src="https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/07/22/822a79ee4043acce3e395eae316811d5.jpeg"
        />
        <div class="tech-3-text text">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga
            dignissimos dolorem eligendi ab quibusdam perferendis at deleniti
            magnam aperiam iste.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="/blogScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```